# CALayer, CAConstraint & Disabling the Animation

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-animation

I was wondering if there's a way to disable the animations for particular layer?

My example here is a bog standard CALayer (the NSView's CALayer), and a sublayer, CATextLayer...

CAtextLayer is nicely tethered to the NSView's CALayer and does exactly what it should.. So no issues there...

how do I turn off the "easing" animations when the view is resized?

Literally this is all I have in my NSView subclass:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var newLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
        newLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor().CGColor
        newLayer.layoutManager = CAConstraintLayoutManager.layoutManager()

        self.layer = newLayer
        self.wantsLayer = true

        var textLayer: CATextLayer = CATextLayer()
        newLayer.insertSublayer(textLayer, atIndex: 0)
        textLayer.string = "Yay Layer"
        textLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        textLayer.name = "textlayer"
        textLayer.fontSize = 42.0;
        textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
        textLayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint(attribute: .MidX, relativeTo: "superlayer", attribute: .MidX, scale: 1.0, offset: 0.0))

        textLayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint(attribute: .MaxY, relativeTo: "superlayer", attribute: .MaxY, scale: 1.0, offset: -50.0))

    }
```

Here's a clip of what I'm getting:

[Screen Capture of Wobbly (eased) Constraints](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61211034/WobblyConstraints.m4v)

What I expected was for the textLayer to adhere to the constraints until it was otherwise given an animator..

Is there any way to stop, remove, or otherwise stop it?

Cheers,

A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textLayer.actions = ["position" : NSNull()]
```